# How to display warning message in the message bar from event Handler

Tags: 2011, event-system

I want to display the below warning message(message bar) on saving a component in Tridion 2013. 
if (component.HasLocalCopies())
                    {
                        xCustomMessage = "There is a localized version of this component.";
                        Logger.WriteInfo(xCustomMessage);

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure that you can only show message bar errors directly from your event system code by raising exceptions from GUI triggered events (like saving a component) - however this would be an error rather than a warning, and would also prevent the component being saved.

In order to have more control over messages in the message bar, you have to undertake a more complicated approach, which will involve a GUI extension to poll for messages which you send from a server - as outlined in [this article](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/signalr_messagecenter.aspx). The advantage of this approach is that you can send any kind of messages from anywhere, but it maybe a bit of a sledgehammer approach for your rather simple problem.